# comparing data in two excel columns based on matching excel columns

Tags: excel, vba, compare

So say I have a spreadsheet in the following format:

```
Sheet 1                    |  Sheet 2
name          email        |  name          email
Mike Jones    mikej@mail   |  John Smith    jsmith@mail    
John Smith    johns@mail   |  Mike Jones    mjones@mail    
John Public   jpublic@mail |  Chris Paul    cpaul@mail        
Chris Paul    cpaul@mail   |  John Public   jpublic@mail
Jim Abram     jambram@mail |
Tim Toole     ttoole@mail  |
```

And I want to compare the emails of entries with matching names and display the names that don't match(I can put all the data on one sheet if necessary), so basically, this would output:

> Mike Jones
>
> John Smith

I'm trying to do this with a formula, but I think I might have to go with a macro... can anyone point me to an example of something like this?

I'm trying something along these lines:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5,0)),(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5,0)), Sheet1!A1, ""),"")
```

and would really like to try to express this as a macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt for a quick and simple formula solution!!

1. Create sheet 3;
2. Name cell A1 = allnames. Paste all names (sheet 1 + sheet 2) on column A
3. Name cell B1 = e-mail.
   Type in B2 = `IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$7,2,0<>VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$I$5,2,0),VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$7,2,0),"")`
4. Copy column B and paste as "values" at collumn C
5. Replace `"#N/A"` by `""`
6. Filter column C by `""`
7. SEE YOUR DESIRED RESULT at COLUMN A.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to insert a column on sheet one, and then filter it to find the duplicates, then you can do this:

```
name        email           Duplicate Count
Mike Jones  mikej@mail          0
John Smith  johns@mail          0
John Public jpublic@mail        1
Chris Paul  cpaul@mail          1
Jim Abram   jambram@mail        0
Tim Toole   ttoole@mail         0
```

The duplicate count column has the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D:D=A2)*1,(B2=E:E)*1)
```

Where column D and column E are the second table you have above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some short code that will store the matches in the workbook. You need to include a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

```
Sub Compare(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngTarget As Range)
    Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim rngTemp As Range
    Const cMailCol As Long = 2

    For Each rngTemp In rng1.Columns(1).Cells
        d.Add rngTemp.Offset(cMailCol - 1).Value, rngTemp.Value
    Next

    For Each rngTemp In rng2.Columns(1).Cells
        If d.Exists(rngTemp.Offset(cMailCol - 1).Value) Then
            rngTarget = d(rngTemp.Offset(cMailCol - 1).Value)
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Call it like  `Compare [A2:B7], [D2:E5], [G2]` to store the matches of the first two ranges in G2!